# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars not working

Tags: angular, typescript

.eslintrc.json:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "excludedFiles": ["*inline-template-*.component.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "parser": "angular" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

angular component:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'angular-movieseat';
  public something = 'asd';

  public somethingFn() {
    console.log('something');
  }
}
```

the `something` and `somethingFn()` are never used, but ESlint doesn't flag them as being unused. In all the questions I've read this should resolve that:

```json
        "no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
```

But it doesn't, any suggestions how to flag these class variables as unused? ESLint does work since it requires the `explicit-member-accessibility` rule.

For completion sake my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a bit different, because we can refer to component variables and methods inside the HTML file of the component, ESLint cannot identify these cases, hence you are not getting that error. The only way to do this, is to manually audit the variables and methods and compare in the HTML and TS file and determine if they are used anywhere.

> Note: Best to do a global search for the variable name to find all usages, to find out, you should also check the parent if the property is accessed via ViewChild.

Comment: I guess that's it. If I make the function `private` I do get an error. Also when I'm importing functions that aren't used. So it's "just" the public members etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently ESLint doesn't "play well" with Angular:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'angular-movieseat';
  private something = 'asd';

  private somethingFn(): void {
    console.log('something');
    const something = 'something';
  }
}
```

When I declare the `const something` I do get the expected error of being an unused variable. Same with the `Input` import at the top of the file.

I also get warnings for `something` and `somethingFn()` when I declare them private.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without actual project ref but I assume your .eslintrc.json should be like this (I put changes only)

```
"files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
```